# Some log and exponential integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, logarithms

I think these should hav some closed form: 
$$\displaystyle\begin{align*}
  & \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\left( 1-x \right)\ln \left( x \right){{\text{e}}^{-x}}}{\pi -x}}\text{d}x \\ 
 & \int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{x{{\text{e}}^{x}}\left( {{\pi }^{2}}+{{\ln }^{2}}x \right)}}\text{d}x \\ 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am not optimistic about that.

Comment: That's a statement. Not a question.

Comment: Where did these integrals come from?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal : These are collected by my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is special about $\pi$ in your integrals.  In the first, if we replace
$\pi$ by $t > 1$, we get

$$\eqalign{J(t) &= \int_0^1 \frac{(1-x) \ln(x) e^{-x}}{t - x} \ dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{-n-1}
\int_0^1 (1-x) \ln(x) e^{-x} x^n\ dx \cr&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{-n-1} (G(n) - G(n+1))\cr
&= t^{-1} G(0) + (1/t - 1) \sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{-n} G(n)}$$
where
$$ \eqalign{G(s) &= \int_0^1 \ln(x) e^{-x} x^s \ dx = \dfrac{d}{ds} \int_0^1 e^{-x} x^s \ dx\cr
&= \dfrac{d}{ds} {\frac {{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(1;\,2+s;\,1)}{{\rm e}^{-1}}}{s+1}}\cr
&= -{\frac {{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(1;\,2+s;\,1)}{{\rm e}^{-1}}}{ \left( s+1
 \right) ^{2}}}-{\frac {
{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(2+s,2+s;\,3+s,3+s;\,-1)}}{ \left( s+1
 \right)  \left( 2+s \right) ^{2}}}
}$$
But I don't know how to get a closed form for the sum.